# python3 regex match pattern but only if it does not end in certain character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a question on how to do replace a string pattern but only if it does not end in an exclamation.

For example, "Thanks, Bob" or "Thanks, Bob." should be replaced with "Thanks, [NAME]" but "Thanks, Bob!" should NOT be replaced.

So far I have this:

```
regex = r"Thanks\,(\s)?(\n+)?[A-Z]?[a-z]+[^!]"
re.sub(regex, "Thanks, [NAME]", text)
```

This works for the case where you have punctuation after "Bob" but won't work for the case "Thanks, Bob"

Any ideas?

Comment: regex101.com is a good place to experiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(Thanks,\s*)[A-Z][a-z]+\b(?!!)
```

and replace with `\1[NAME]`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pVJFdl/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(Thanks%2C%5Cs*)%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5Cb(%3F!!)):

[image]

The point is that you need to use a word boundary `\b` after `[a-z]+` and add a [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!!)` *right after*.

**Details**

- `(Thanks,\s*)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): `Thanks,` and 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` - an uppercase letter and then 1+ lowercase ones
- `\b` - a word boundary, the next char cannot be letter/digit/`_`
- `(?!!)` - no `!` immediately to the right of the current location is allowed.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/1Tgc3R):

```
import re
rx = r"(Thanks,\s*)[A-Z][a-z]+\b(?!!)"
strs = ["Thanks, Bob", "Thanks, Bob.", "Thanks, Bob!"]
for s in strs: 
    print( re.sub(rx, r"\1[NAME]", s) )
```

Output:

```
Thanks, [NAME]
Thanks, [NAME].
Thanks, Bob!
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expression is just fine, we'd be slightly modifying that to:

```
^Thanks\s*,\s*([A-Z]?[a-z]*)\s*[^!]?$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UaHRLj/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^Thanks\s*,\s*([A-Z]?[a-z]*)\s*[^!]?$"

test_str = ("Thanks, Bob\n"
    "Thanks, Bob.\n"
    "Thanks, Bob!")

subst = "Thanks, [NAME]"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```